# Linux scsi ata cmd write or read sometimes work and sometimes didn't work when transfer length is over 1345

Tags: linux, command, scsi, sata, ata

My code is as follows:

```
unsigned char cmd[16];
cmd[0] = WRITE_16;
//lba is start address
cmd[2] = (lba >> 54) & 0xFF;
cmd[3] = (lba >> 48) & 0xFF;
cmd[4] = (lba >> 40) & 0xFF;
cmd[5] = (lba >> 32) & 0xFF;
cmd[6] = (lba >> 24) & 0xFF;
cmd[7] = (lba >> 16) & 0xFF;
cmd[8] = (lba >> 8) & 0xFF;
cmd[9] = lba & 0xFF;
//len is transfer length
cmd[10] = (len >> 24) & 0xFF;
cmd[11] = (len >> 16) & 0xFF;
cmd[12] = (len >> 8) & 0xFF;
cmd[13] = len & 0xFF;

void* buffer;
buffer = malloc(len*512);
__u64 buffer_len = 512*len;
io_hdr.interface_id = 'S';
io_hdr.cmd_len = sizeof(cmd);
io_hdr.mx.sb_len = sizeof(sense);
io_hdr.dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_TO_FROM_DEV;
io_hdr.dxfer_len = buffer_len;
io_hdr.dxferp = buffer;
io_hdr.cmdp = cmd;
io_hdr.sbp = sense;
io_hdr.timeout = 30000;
ioctl(fd, SG_IO, &io_hdr);
```

If I send cmd transfer length over 1345, it sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't work. If  thetransfer length grows up, the portion that doesn't work goes up too. There's no uart log or kernel log when cmd doesn't work.

ps. If cmd doesn't work, errno says `22(invalid argument)`

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing the bytes in the SCSI CDB to zero, so sometimes there's trash in `cmd[1]`, `cmd[14]`, and `cmd[15]`.  Add a call to `memset` up at the top, or initialize the array with `= { };`.

Also, I know a bunch of examples use this technique for initializing the command structure, but man, it's really going to drive you nuts.  I recommend defining an `__attribute__ ((packed))` structure for the CDB that uses bitfields.

Lastly, the line `cmd[2] = (lba >> 54) & 0xFF;` should shift `lba` by 56 bits, not 54 bits.

Comment: Thank you but when i try which you comment it doesn't work... i don't know why command sometimes get in the device and sometimes can't...